# Using a temporary to initialize multiple members

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization-list

In older C++98, I don't believe there was any good way to reuse a temporary result in an initializer list to initialize multiple members of an object.

Has this changed at all in newer versions of C++ (11, 14, 17)?

Consider the following code:

```
//
// compileShaders()
//
// Takes a string containing the source code to possibly hundreds of shaders 
// for an effect (In this case, there are only 2 shaders for this effect)
//
// Returns a vector of compiled bytecode for each shader in the effect
//
std::vector<std::string> compileShaders(
    const std::string& sourceCode, 
    const RenderTargetLayout& layout);

//
// class ScaleDownEffect
//
// Scales image to 1/4 in each dimension by using two 1/2 passes
//
class ScaleDownEffect
{
public:
    ScaleDownEffect(const TargetImage& targetImage)
        :   m_renderTarget(targetImage),

            m_firstPassShader(      
                compileShaders(
                    ScaleDownEffectShaderSource, 
                    m_renderTarget.getLayout()
                    )[0], 
                m_renderTarget.getWidth()  / 2, 
                m_renderTarget.getHeight() / 2
                ),

            m_secondPassShader(     
                compileShaders(
                    ScaleDownEffectShaderSource, 
                    m_renderTarget.getLayout()
                    )[1], 
                m_renderTarget.getWidth()  / 4, 
                m_renderTarget.getHeight() / 4
                )
    {
    }

private:
    RenderTarget m_renderTarget;
    Shader m_firstPassShader;
    Shader m_secondPassShader;
};
```

`compileShaders()` is a very heavyweight call, and I don't really think it's a good idea to call it twice when I don't really have to.

**Note** None of the three objects being initialized have default ctors, so doing it in the body of the function is not really an option.

What do we think? Is there any good way for me to do this, or should I switch to smart pointers and dynamically allocate the objects I contain?

Comment: Does shader have a default constructor (ie can it be default constructed, and then assigned in the constructor)?

Comment: Nope - Neither `Shader` nor `RenderTarget` have default ctors (And I don't own the code - It's a library from another team)

Comment: you could write a method that holds the result of the call in a static variable and use that to initialize the members, a bit hackish but works also in pre C++11

Comment: @tobi303 - I hope it doesn't come down to that, but it is an idea. It might be one of several messy alternatives by-the-looks-of-it.

Comment: @tobi303: Before doing that, I'd rather save the temporary in an additional private data member and clear it when the constructor has finished.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Actually yeah, good point. If I'm already going to pay the cost of permanently storing a temporary, I might-as-well at-least do it in a thread-safe way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested type:

```
class ScaleDownEffect
{
    struct Shaders
    {
        explicit Shaders(const std::vector<std::string>& s, unsigned int w, unsigned int h)
            : m_firstPassShader(      
                s[0], 
                w  / 2, 
                h / 2
                ),
              m_secondPassShader(     
                s[1], 
                w  / 4, 
                h / 4
                )
        {}

        Shader m_firstPassShader;
        Shader m_secondPassShader;
    };
    RenderTarget m_renderTarget;
    Shaders m_shaders;

public:
    ScaleDownEffect(const TargetImage& targetImage)
    :   m_renderTarget(targetImage),
    ,   m_shaders(compileShaders(ScaleDownEffectShaderSource,
                                     m_renderTarget.getLayout()),
                  m_renderTarget.getWidth(),
                  m_renderTarget.getHeight())
    {
    }
};
```

You could also pass a reference to `m_renderTarget` to the nested type's c'tor instead of width and height (which I just assumed to be of type `unsigned int`, btw).

There is one disadvantage in that you now need to access the first pass shader e.g. as `m_shaders.m_firstPassShader`. I recommend adding (inline) getter methods, even if they return references, and even if they are private, to isolate code using the shaders from changes in the way they are stored.

Comment: Actually yeah! This is a really good idea. It solves everything - I get to still contain both objects in my class without dynamic allocation, and it works without using copy or move.

Answer (score 8):

You can use delegating constructor since C++11:

```
class ScaleDownEffect
{
     ScaleDownEffect(const TargetImage& targetImage,
                     const std::vector<std::string>& shaders)
     : m_renderTarget(targetImage),
       m_firstPassShader(shaders[0],
                         m_renderTarget.getWidth()  / 2,
                         m_renderTarget.getHeight() / 2),
       m_secondPassShader(shaders[1],
                          m_renderTarget.getWidth() / 4,
                          m_renderTarget.getHeight() / 4)
     {}

public:
    ScaleDownEffect(const TargetImage& targetImage)
        : ScaleDownEffect(targetImage,
                          compileShaders(ScaleDownEffectShaderSource,
                                         targetImage.getLayout())) 
    {
    }

private:
    RenderTarget m_renderTarget;
    Shader m_firstPassShader;
    Shader m_secondPassShader;
};
```

Comment: The snag with this is that you're calling `targetImage.getLayout()`, but my original code needs to call `m_renderTarget.getLayout()`.

Comment: Can `TargetImage` be moved so `getLayout()` would return same/correct value ?

Comment: Is there a way that I can initialize `m_renderTarget` first, call `compileShaders()`, and then pass that result to the next constructor?

Comment: @ask_me_about_loom To use constructor delegation, the initialization list must contain only the constructor to delegate to.

Comment: so you could chain it - and have `ScaleDownEffect(const TargetImage& targetImage)`   call `ScaleDownEffect(RenderTarget&& targetImage)` call `ScaleDownEffect(RenderTarget&& targetImage, const std::vector<std::string>& shaders)`

Comment: @UKMonkey Cool idea! Will it work though if those classes also don't provide copy/move constructors?

Comment: You have still the possibility to change to `std::unique_ptr<RenderTarget> m_renderTarget;` then...

Comment: @Jarod42 That's exactly what I figured I'd have to resolve to doing. Sucks though that C++ can't handle this properly, considering the language prides itself on trying to have zero-overhead.

Comment: @ask_me_about_loom no, probably not; but there's no reason why you shouldn't make them movable ;)